# Manually add an element to a selection in d3

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to programmatically create a table in d3 with quarters across the top and values along the left.  Given a vector of quarters `["q1", "q2", "q3", "q4"]`, I would like the table:

```
   | q1 | q2 | q3 | q4 |
v1 |    |    |    |    |
v2 |    |    |    |    |
```

What I am getting when running the code below is:

```
   | q2 | q3 | q4 |
v1 |    |    |    |
v2 |    |    |    |
```

Note the first column is missing.  I am using the following code:

```
var qtrs = ["q1", "q2", "q3", "q4"];

var info = d3.select("body"),
    thead = info.append("thead"),
    tbody = info.append("tbody");

thead.append("tr").append("th").text("")
thead.select("tr")
    .selectAll("th")
    .data(qtrs)
    .enter()
    .insert("th")
    .text(function (d) { return (d);  });

tbody.append("tr").insert("td").text("Value 1")
            tbody.append("tr").insert("td").text("Value 2")
            tbody.selectAll("tr").selectAll("td").data(qtrs).enter()
            .append("td").text("0.0");
```

Which is also available here: http://jsfiddle.net/TpCJk/

The part I am struggling with is how to manually select/add a single element (ie the first column) to the table while using `data(qtrs)` to automatically generate the rest of the columns.

What seems to be happening is that the selectAll is also selecting the (manually created) empty cell and overwriting it.  I've tried adding the first column later (putting `thead.select("tr").insert("th").text("...");` after creating `th` however it always seems to land at the end of the table, not the start.

Note that the `qtrs` array here is an example, in my full application it will depend on the data passed to it (ie could be longer or shorter).  The "Value 1" and "Value 2" lines are fixed.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you already have a table (header) cell that is not specified through the data. The way D3 matches data elements to DOM elements (in the `data()` function) is by index by default. That is, the first data element you pass in matches the first table (header) cell, which in your particular case is already there. Therefore, it is not in the `.enter()` selection.

The best way to fix this is to simply provide a function that tells D3 how to match data to DOM elements. The code

```
thead.select("tr")
     .selectAll("th")
     .data(qtrs, function(d) { return d; })
     .enter()
     .insert("th")
     .text(function (d) { return (d);  });
```

Inserts all the table headers correctly. If you specify the same matching function when adding the table cells, they will be added correctly (i.e. the correct number of columns) as well.

Comment: Great - works perfectly, thanks!  Having thought about it, I now even understand why it works (was a complete mystery to me at first).