# d3 Adding cells to an existing table

Tags: html, d3.js, append, html-table

I'm having some problems getting this to work.  I have an existing HTML table and would like to use d3 to append some data to the table.

Here's the HTML table:

```
<table>
     <thead>
     <tr id="table_header">
       <th>Header 1</th>
       <th>Header 2</th>
       <th>Header 3</th>
       <th>Header 4</th>
       <th>Header 5</th>
       <th>Header 6</th>
     </tr>  
     </thead>
     <tbody id="data_table">
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

For now I just want to append some additional headers to this so I use d3

```
<script>
    d3.json("data.php", function(monthly_growth) {

    d3.select("#table_header").selectAll("th").data(monthly_growth).enter().append("th").text(function(d) {return d.MONTH;});

    });
</script>
```

I hope this isn't too hard to understand without having the actual data available.  Basically my data set has values for every month for the next several years.  I want to create a new  header for each month in the data set.  Currently my code above is appending  headers to my original table but it's missing the first 6 months of the data set.  I suspect my d3 code is starting to append the data at the first Header which is not what I want obviously.

I also tried giving my 6th header an ID and appending to that but it didn't quite work out well.  It seemed to have started a new row of headers underneath it. Besides I feel like that isn't the proper way of doing this.

Comment: This looks like it's almost exactly the same as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316480/manually-add-an-element-to-a-selection-in-d3/).

Comment: Yes this is exactly it! Thanks, I got it to work.  I'm still trying to understand WHY adding function(d) to my .data function helps with the indexing though.

Comment: I found a better way to do this besides selecting all th elements.  So I created a class to the new th I want created. so that my new code is  'code' d3.select(#table_header).selectAll(th.month).data(monthly_growth).enter().append(""th).attr('class', 'month').text(function(d) {return d.MONTH;});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did this by creating a new class so that d3 appends new types of  instead of "thinking" I want to select the  already there.:

```
<script>
    d3.json("data.php", function(monthly_growth) {

    d3.select("#table_header").selectAll("th.month").data(monthly_growth).enter().append("th").attr('class', 'month').text(function(d) {return d.MONTH;});

    });
</script>
```