# d3 Nested Selections - Table Appending Works in d3.v2 but not in d3.v3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

## Problem

I am appending to an existing table dynamically following the [example in the D3 API reference](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data). The problem is, this code works when I include d3.v2.js, but doesn't work when I switch to d3.v3.js.

When using d3.v2, everything appends as I would expect it to. When using d3.v3, only the first object in `sessions` gets appended and the rest are nowhere to be found. I have created two fiddles showing the different behavior.

### Fiddles

- [JSFiddle: v2 behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/d79n5/)
- [JSFiddle: v3 behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/6CK5E/)

The code I am using to append the items in `sessions` to the table `hurricanes` is shown here:

### Javascript

```
var sessions = [
    {name: 'Fred',     year: 2014},
    {name: 'Bill',     year: 1970},
    {name: 'Pookie',   year: 1892},
    {name: 'Hurry',    year: 1941},
    {name: 'Nick',     year: 1953}
];

d3.select('#hurricanes').select('tbody').selectAll('tr')
        .data(sessions, function(d) { return d; })
    .enter().append('tr')
        .selectAll('td')
        .data(function(d) { return d3.values(d); })
    .enter().append('td')
        .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

### HTML

```
<table id='hurricanes'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Andrew</td>
      <td>1992</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bob</td>
      <td>1991</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Irene</td>
      <td>2011</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Katrina</td>
      <td>2005</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ivan</td>
      <td>2004</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have read the [guidelines regarding switching from 2.0 to 3.0](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Upgrading-to-3.0) but I haven't found anything of use.

## Question

**Why does using d3.v3.js change the way the table is being appended? And what can I do to fix it?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems that lead to the strange result you are getting.

The first issue is that you have existing elements on your page that have no data bound to them, so when you make your initial selection, you are selecting the 5 existing `tr` elements. This means that we should expect the `.enter()` selection to be empty, and no new elements will be created.

The second issue results from the first. Since there is no data bound to the existing elements, when your key function gets called, it checks for the values associated with the existing elements, and gets back `undefined`. It seems that d3.v2 and d3.v3 handle this error differently, but in both cases it is an error, and the `.enter()` selection ends up containing one extra element in the case of d3.v3, and 5 extra elements in the case of d3.v2.

You can see that this is happening by logging the value of `d` to the console in your key function:

```
d3.select('#hurricanes').select('tbody').selectAll('tr')
  .data(sessions, function(d) { 
     console.log(d);
     return d; 
  })
```

You will notice that the output is

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
Object {name: "Fred", year: 2014}
Object {name: "Bill", year: 1970}
Object {name: "Pookie", year: 1892}
Object {name: "Hurry", year: 1941}
Object {name: "Nick", year: 1953}
```

You say that it is working in d3.v2, but that is not the case. You are simply getting a different errant result. Since there are only 5 objects in your data array, you should expect to only have 5 `tr` elements in your output after the data is joined. In other words, there should be nothing in the `.enter()` selection, because there are already the same number of `tr` elements as there are datapoints in your dataset.

If you remove the key function, d3 will revert to binding the data by index, rather than by key. When you do this you will notice that you now get the expected result of 5 elements with both d3 versions:

[d3.v2 JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W5s3L/)

[d3.v3 JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8LWPd/)

Now the data is bound to the originally existing elements. But there's a problem now, because the bound data is not being reflected in the elements themselves. In other words, the row that says 'Andrew 1992' is bound to data `{name: 'Fred' year: 2014}`, and so on down the line. To update to the new values you would need to select the existing nodes and use the `.text()` function to update the elements with their newly bound data.

Leave that all aside though, because that's not what you're trying to accomplish anyways. You want to have 10 elements in your output, the original 5, and 5 newly created from the dataset. To do that you either need to:

---

**(1)** Add entries for 'Andrew', 'Bob', 'Irene', 'Katrina', and 'Ivan' to the `sessions` data, remove the existing html elements representing them, and then build a complete table from the data.

[**Method 1 JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4TKkG/)

---

OR

---

**(2)** Create an empty selection within the `tbody` and append the new elements to that:

```
d3.select('#hurricanes').select('tbody').selectAll('.new-entry')
  .data(sessions)
  .enter().append('tr')
    .attr('class', 'new-entry')
    .selectAll('td')
      .data(function(d) { return d3.values(d); })
      .enter().append('td')
        .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

[**Method 2 JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fJKFL/)

---

I hope that helps. If you want to read up on nested selections and key functions, here are a couple excellent posts from Mike Bostock himself:

[Nested Selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/)

[Object Constancy](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/)

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough answer! Though I am confused when you say the `.enter()` selection should be empty. The reason I am adding the key function is to ensure D3 doesn't match my new data with the first 5 `tr` entries. Since I have 5 unmatched data points, the `enter()` selection shouldn't be empty. Then it seems that the problem is that the data for the existing `tr` elements is `undefined` and that is causing D3 some headaches, as you stated in your answer. I wouldn't have expected this. But thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: My confusion is stemming from the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316480/manually-add-an-element-to-a-selection-in-d3/

Comment: In your case, you cannot use simply `d` as the return value from the key function, because each element in your data array is an object. A key must be a string. You could use `d.name` as a key, since each hurricane has a unique name in your data, however you'll then throw an error because `d` is undefined for the 5 existing elements on your page. You could select the elements manually and use `.datum()` to assign data to them without computing a join, but that seems like adding a lot of extra complexity. I'm running out of characters, so I'll address your first question in a second comment.

Comment: The `.enter()` selection should be empty in your case because d3's data-join assumes that there will be exactly one datum per element in the selection. If there is a discrepancy, this is handled by providing selections for `.enter()` and `.exit()`.

Comment: If you had 3 elements on the page, and you provided your 5 datapoints, d3 would bind the first 3 datapoints to your existing elements, and would make 2 places in the `.enter()` selection, from which you can create 2 elements to satisfy the unused datapoints. If there were 8 existing elements, the first 5 would be bound to data, and the remaining 3 would be added to the `.exit()` selection so you could remove them.